Munkres topology corollary 6.7
Munkres in his "Topology a first course" textbook has the following corollary 6.7 (on page 43):
Corollary 6.7. Let $B$ be a nonempty set. Then the following are equivalent:

$B$ is finite.
There is a surjective function from a section of the positive integers onto $B$ .
There is an injective function from $B$ into a section of the positive integers.

Given that Munkres previously defines a section of positive integers in such a way that $S_1=\emptyset$ is also considered a section of the positive integers, I don't believe that the stipulation that $B$ be nonempty is needed and so I am puzzled as to why Munkres has stated the corollary in this manner. The proof supplied won't work for the empty set case but all three statements are trivially true for the empty set and so equivalent among them. Am I missing something?

They probably want to avoid having to distinguish cases in the proof, but since i have not read the book there may be another reason.

There is no surjection, or function for that matter, from a non-empty set into the empty set.

@AsafKaragila Indeed but we don't need that. All we need is a surjection from a (any) section of the positive integers onto the empty set. So we pick the section S1 = {} (according to Munkres definitions) and the empty function is the surjection we're looking for.

Right. This can very well be a "force of habit" kind of thing. As someone who wrote several lecture notes so far, I can tell you that it can be quite a thing.
